# Reste telerik Theme after add <Style>

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

I want to change my WPF & C# code to telerik. Before change i have HeaderContentControl with some Workspaces

**My XAML code**

```
<HeaderedContentControl 
      Content="{Binding Workspaces}"
      ContentTemplate="{StaticResource WorkspacesTemplate}"
      Style="{StaticResource MainHCCStyle}"
/>
```

**My Resources**

```
<Style x:Key="MainHCCStyle" TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedContentControl}>
 <Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedContentControl}>
      <DockPanel>
        <ContentPresenter 
          ContentSource="Content" 
           ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
         />
       </DockPanel>
     </ControlTemplate>
   </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
</Style>

<DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspacesTemplate">
        <TabControl 
      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}"
      Margin="4"
      />
</DataTemplate>
```

After modify code to Telerik my code looks like

**My XAML code**

```
<telerik:RadTabbedWindow
  Content="{Binding Workspaces}"
  ContentTemplate="{StaticResource WorkspacesTemplate}"
  telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Office2016"
  Style="{StaticResource MainHCCStyle}"
  />
```

**My Resources**

```
<Style x:Key="MainHCCStyle" TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadTabbedWindow}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadTabbedWindow}">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <ContentPresenter 
              ContentSource="Content" 
              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
              />
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

<DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspacesTemplate">
        <TabControl 
      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}"
      Margin="4"
      />

</DataTemplate>
```

Workspaces wors ok, but Telerik theme doesn't work ( **telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Office2016"**). Styles only activate if I delete them **Style="{StaticResource MainHCCStyle}"**, however then workspaces doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom `Style` that targets `RadTabbedWindow` is overriding its `ControlTemplate` (via the `Template` property). This means that the default look and feel of the control is replaced with the `Dock` panel defined in the `Style`.

To make this work, set the `ContentTemplate` of `RadTabbedWindow`, instead of its Template property.